# NSValueTransformer for NSPopupButton on CoreData integer attribute

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nspopupbutton, nsvaluetransformer

I have a CoreData/SQLite app with an NSPopupButton presenting the possible values for some entity attribute (an integer). It automatically shows the attribute value in the database. The user must be able to assign another value so my code generates an array of all possible values on start-up. In my XIB, I have a NSObject for the button and an NSArrayController for the possible values. Bindings are done and everything works fine.

Of course, using only numbers is not clear for the user, so I created a value transformer to replace numbers by words on the popup button: 1=>Red, 2=>Green, 3=>Blue.

The problem is that only the selected Popup item is replaced by a word. And when I choose another value with the Popup button to modify the entity attribute, it doesn't save it. I see it by selecting another object in the TableView then coming back to the modified one and the Popup will indicate NoValue.

I don't understand why. Thank you for your help.

Here is the code of the header file "ColorOption.h":

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ColorOption : NSArrayController {
    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *colorPopup;
    NSArray *theNumbers;
}
@property (retain) NSPopUpButton *colorPopup;
@property (readwrite, copy) NSArray *theNumbers;
@end

@interface StatusTransformer : NSValueTransformer {
}
@end
```

Here is the code of the implementation file "ColorOption.m":

```
#import "ColorOption.h"

@implementation ColorOption
@synthesize colorPopup;
@synthesize theNumbers;

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setTheNumbers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],nil]];
    StatusTransformer *statusTrans = [[[StatusTransformer alloc] init] autorelease];
    [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:statusTrans forName:@"StatusTransformer"];
}
@end

@implementation StatusTransformer
+ (Class)transformedValueClass { return [NSString class]; }
+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation { return YES; }
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    switch ([value intValue]) {
        case 1:
        return @"Red";
        break;
        case 2:
        return @"Green";
        break;
        case 3:
        return @"Blue";
        break;
        default:
        return @"";
        break;
    }
}

-(id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    if ([@"Red" isEqualToString:value]) return [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    if ([@"Green" isEqualToString:value]) return [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
    if ([@"Blue" isEqualToString:value]) return [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];    
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: I've been struggling with popup buttons and value transformers for a while. Could you explain what your bindings were in your answer?  I don't understand where theNames fits in.

Comment: Hi Rdelmar, see reply at bottom of page and write if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reviewing my questions and see that this one has been left unanswered. However in the meantime I had found the answer which I'll post now so it may help others.

The mistake I did was to define the array of integer values while what I should have done is to define the array of words populating the popup button. Here is the full solution:

Header file :

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ColorOption : NSArrayController {
    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *colorPopup;
    NSArray *theNames;
}
@property (strong) NSPopUpButton *colorPopup;
@property (readwrite, copy) NSArray *theNames;
@end

@interface StatusTransformer : NSValueTransformer {
}
@end
```

Implementation file

```
#import "ColorOption.h"

@implementation ColorOption
@synthesize colorPopup = _colorPopup;
@synthesize theNames = _theNames;

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setTheNames:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Red"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Green"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Blue"],nil]];
    StatusTransformer *statusTrans = [[[StatusTransformer alloc] init] autorelease];
    [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:statusTrans forName:@"StatusTransformer"];
}
@end

@implementation StatusTransformer
+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSString class];
}
+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
    return YES;
}
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    switch ([value intValue]) {
        case 1: {
            return @"Red";
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            return @"Green";
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            return @"Blue";
            break;
        }
        default: {
            return nil;
            break;
        }
    }
}

-(id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    if ([@"Red" isEqualToString:value]) return [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    if ([@"Green" isEqualToString:value]) return [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
    if ([@"Blue" isEqualToString:value]) return [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];    
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Now in the bindings inspector of Xcode, the value transformer must be applied to "Content Values" and "Selected Object" for the popup button.

Comment: 1. Drop an Object (blue cube) on the object list of your Xib. On the identity inspector, give the class name where your popup button and array are defined (in my example, it's ColorOption. Right-click on it and link the name of the popup button (colorPopup) to the actual button on your view.

Comment: 2) Add an Array Controller. On its Bindings inspector, define Controller Content as follows: Content Array -> Bind to name of Object and Model Key Path = theNames.

Comment: 3) Click on the popup button to display its Bindings inspector and configure Value Selection as follows: Content -> Bind to name of Array Controller and Controller Key = arrangedObjects, then Content Values -> Bind to name of Array Controller and Controller Key = arrangedObjects and Value Transformer = name of Value Transformer, then Selected Object -> Bind to name of Array Controller linked to the entity where the data fits and Controller Key = selection and Model Key Path = name of the related entity attribute and Value Transformer = name of the Value Transformer.

Comment: I think I've already done all that -- the strange thing is that if I log "value" in the transformedValue method it gives me the array that the array controller is bound to instead of individual values in that array. I've used value transformers several times successfully with table views, so I'm not sure what's going on here.